# force iphone into lock mode

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

i'm trying to create a timer (using NSTimer) that when it fires, the Iphone will lock itself.

or at least shut off the screen.

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think so. This would override a custom user setting. It is possible however to STOP the screen from dimming so perhaps there is a way.

Comment: yeah, i know this option. that is the reason i thought it is possible to do the opposite.
thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GraphicsServices framework, and a function `GSEventLockDevice();` that locks the device, but it isn't documented (private framework) and very likely to be rejected by Apple. But if you don't plan to submit to the App Store, this is an option.